# How to auto-add item to a list from an incoming serial data?

Tags: c#, gmap.net

I'm trying to trace the real time position of an object using c# and GMap.net. Inside GMap.net, in order to trace a route, I have to use a `List<PointLatLng>` and then unify them using a `Pen`.

The problem is that I don't know where the object will be at the beginning, so I have no points to add, a part the first one.

Is it possible to add only one point to a list and update it in real time?

Or, it is possible to save the first point into a variable and then add the other points using the pervious variable's name incrementing a number by 1 each time the data is received from the serial port and then refreshing the list with the new points?

`

```
List<PointLatLng> points = new List<PointLatLng>();
var coordinates = new List<PointLatLng> { new PointLatLng(GPS_Latitude, GPS_Longitude) };
coordinates.Add(new PointLatLng(GPS_Latitude, GPS_Longitude));
GMapOverlay trace = new GMapOverlay("Real Time Position");
GMapRoute carroute = new GMapRoute(coordinates, "Traiectory");
gMapControl1.Overlays.Add(trace);
trace.Routes.Add(carroute);
//Pen redPen = new Pen(Color.Red, 3);
carroute.Stroke = new Pen(Color.Red, 3);
```

`

By this way I have only the first point but not the others. Data are received with 1hz frequence with serial port. I mean: the list count only one item and not more even if I received more than 1 datum.

Comment: It's still a little unclear what you are asking. What problem are you having with making the first coordinate you get from the GPS unit then first item you add to the list?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Yes** either of those solutions is possible.

---

You can have a list of points and then call `.Add()` whenever you want to add a point to the list (it wouldn't make sense to use a `List` if you're only saving a single point - if that's the case see next example). This way you have a history of all the points. You can always get the newest point by accessing the item at the last index in the list:

```
// Create list and (optionally) add the first point to it
var points = new List<Point> { new Point(x, y) };

// Add a new point to the list whenever you want
points.Add(new Point(newX, newY));

// Get the most recent point by getting the item at the last index
var newestPoint = points[points.Count - 1];  // Note: this will fail if the list is empty
```

---

You can also have a single point variable and then update it's coordinates either by changing the values independently: or by assigning it a new Point:

```
var myPoint = new Point(x, y);

// Update coordinates independently whenever you want
myPoint.X = newX; 
myPoint.Y = newY;

// Or just assign a new Point
myPoint = new Point(newX, newY);
```

Comment: I tried another way: using different markers. but, I'm not able to create more than one marker using the coordinates ( i have to manually create them even if I want them to create by themselves). In addiction I can't update the position of the marker when the data income through the serial port. do you know how to do or what to do?

Comment: You should update your question with the code. It's not clear how you're creating markers from the data, or how often new data is coming in. I'm not familiar with gmap either, so someone else may be able to help better if you make your question very specific and show the problematic code.